# Where is the best place to ask this?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I didn't know what to put in the title that would be brief, so here is the question:

> I am interested in web development, but I am not entirely sure what route/what things I should learn for what I want to do. I am interested in creating websites for desktop in addition to a mobile app which uses the same data from the website.
>
> For example, let's say my desktop website is a phone book—stores numbers, names, emails, addresses, etc—with interface to view entries, and add and delete new entries. I also want to then design a native mobile app which can also do the same things by viewing and modifying the same data the website uses.
>
> Sorry I don't know how to explain this any better, I am obviously new to this area so I don't really know how to phrase this. I am not lacking in programming knowledge though—I do know a fair share of Java and C++, as well as some HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

There are no Stack Exchange sites where a question of this scope is suitable.

Every person would have a different opinion on this and any answer could be considered to be correct.

This makes the question unsuitable for our format of Q&A, where we expect answers to be based on facts and where an objectively "best" answer can be determined.

Such a question ends up as a poll - essentially asking people for "what do you think?".

Comment: I see, I figured it would be subjective, but I was hoping there was a general consensus for doing something like this (e.g. use any JavaScript framework with any RDBMS or something). Where would be the best place to ask such a question outside of StackExchange then?

Comment: I have no idea. There are many developer forums out there and you might have luck in our chat rooms. My opinion is that you should just start - whenever you are stuck, research the specific thing you are stuck on then keep going. Learn by doing.